# Cursor returning 0

Tags: android, mysql, cursor

I have a function where I want to get the sum of values on a MySQL database table's row. This is my code:

```
public int getSum(int var) {

    int x=0;
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT sum(amount) FROM donations WHERE aid = '"+aid+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("shareity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            x = cursor.getInt(0);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    Log.d("id", "Id" + "," + x);
    return x;
}
```

And I'm calling this in the onCreate() like this:

```
getSum(idk);
```

where `idk` is an integer. But my this returns 0. Can I know why please? The table's row I want to get the sum of, is also integer.

Comment: Try the query directly in mysql and see what you get for the given `aid`..also `WHERE aid = '"+aid+"'";` you perhaps added the wrong variable since the function argument says its `var`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, the `var` corresponds to the `idk` I send in the onCreate() function right? I have initiated `idk=0` in the class. Does this make a difference?

Comment: in `getSum` you have no `aid`

Comment: When you call the function as `getSum(idk);` meaning you are sending some value as argument and the value is now in the variable `idk` , the function definition is `public int getSum(int var)` so inside the function it only knows `var` and in the query you have `WHERE aid = '"+aid+"'"` it should be `WHERE aid = '"+var+"'"`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, okay I did as you mentioned, but still nothing.

Comment: Looks like something wrong, try to log the query and see if the data is going properly inside the function. You may try those queries directly into mysql to see whats happening.

Comment: yeah I tried, the correct value is passed into the function. I think something is wrong with the cursor. Is my cursor code and sql query correct? @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Query looks correct else you would have got error message from mysql. For some reason its getting `sum` 0 which could in case when `where condition` does not satisfy the data in the table.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I tried running the sql command on the phpmyadmin table too. I get the sum of the rows correctly. IDK what's going wrong when sending it to the android code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76878/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-abhik-chakraborty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The problem was with the SQLite database. I had to use a php file to download the database from the mysql server to the local Sqlite server and then loop through it